# Dynamically generating a email template in Struts 2

Tags: struts2

The scenario is that a user request a leave. When he request leave then a email is send to the approver and the user containing the details about the leave. I am Stuck at this Point that how to create a template which will be automatically updated by the name of the user requesting leave .I saw asp.net app in that the implemented in a template by using something like this

```
Requestor   :   {REQUESTORS NAME}
Leave Type  :   {REQUEST TYPE}
Start Date  :   {REQUEST START DATE}
End Date    :   {REQUEST END DATE}
Number of days  :   {DAYS REQUESTED}
```

Any idea how to create such a template dynamically using struts 2 any smallest of the guidance would be very helpful

Comment: Do you mean dynamically generate e-mail FROM template?

Comment: Yup means the template will be filled with the details of the user thats what i am trying to do.and then attach that template in email and send

Comment: @ChetanPulate:i am not sure what problem you are getting as this can easily be done,create a Velocity template and you can use Velocity to fill those placeholder when Velocity engine will process your .vm  file before sending the email.Where exactly you are strucked?

Comment: Sorry umesh sir if the question appeared silly to u but i have no idea about velocity or free marker never used it u know still on the learning curve i guess to long for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use some template engine to create template and populate it with your data. Take a look at FreeMarker template engine http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/freemarker.html. It is used in Struts2 by default so there is no need to add it separately.