# Sending value from action to the jsp which is not redirected from the action

Tags: java, jsp, email, struts2, ognl

I am using JSP page to send as email template from my action class

that is `aaa.jsp` accept email_id from user then redirect to Mail action for sending `hashcode` to user then redirected to `yyy.jsp` to enter the `hashcode` sent to `emil_id` provided by user. I use `xxx.jsp` as email template.

my `xxx.jsp` is

```
<html>
  <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <s:property value="hashcode"/>
 </body>
</html>
```

I have an action class that sends an email to the user with an authentication code for the registration purpose.

`checkAndMail` is used to check whether this mail is registered already and convert the `xxx.jsp` page to string

```
public String checkAndMail() throws Exception{
this.hashcode="9048075352";//getters and setters are used for hashxode and is of type String
/***********
   code for searching whether the email is registered already
************/

    HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();
    HttpServletResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new HttpServletResponseWrapper(response) {
    private final StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

    @Override
    public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException {
        return new PrintWriter(sw);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return sw.toString();
    }
    };
    setHashcode(hashcode);
       request.getRequestDispatcher("aa/bb/xxx.jsp").include(request,
        responseWrapper);
    String result1 = responseWrapper.toString();
    sendMailNew("christinchacko@gmail.com", result1,"AssignMail" );
   TARGET = "success";

}
```

I call `sendMailNew` from `checkAndMail` for sending mail. My `sendMailNew` method which is used for sending mail is

```
public synchronized void sendMailNew(String mailTo,String Content,String type) throws Exception 
{
    String TEXT="";  
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", HOST);
    props.put("mail.smtp.user", USER);
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", AUTH);
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", STARTTLS);
    props.put("mail.smtp.debug", DEBUG);
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

    try {
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
            session.setDebug(true);
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

            //message.setText(TEXT);
      if(type.equals("AssignMail"))
    {
            message.setContent(Content, "text/html");

    }
            message.setSubject(SUBJECT);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(FROM));
            message.addRecipients(RecipientType.TO, mailTo);
            message.saveChanges();
            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD);
            transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Exception in Mail.sendMail" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

My question is how to pass a value (here parameter is `hashcode`) from `checkAdnMail` to `xxx.jsp`

this action class is redirected to `yyy.jsp` for entering the `hashcode` that should be sent to the user's email address.

Reference: [Struts2 - How can I get the result of a JSP page as a string in an action class (for emails)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25936387/struts2-how-can-i-get-the-result-of-a-jsp-page-as-a-string-in-an-action-class/25936565#25936565)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/13623220/1700321.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a value using a request attribute. For example

```
request.setAttribute("hashcode", hashcode);
```

then in JSP you have to reference a request object in the struts tag or just use JSP EL

```
<s:property value="#request.hashcode"/>
```

or

```
${hashcode}
```

The last value is not escaped, be cautious if you have wrong characters in the code.

Comment: when I used ${hashcode} it shows error in jsp page as "According to TLD or Attributive directive in tag file, attribute value does not accept any expressions" ....<s:property value="#request.hashcode"/> did not work for me it shows null value..

Comment: Don't use JSP EL in struts tags, as for the second you can make it working.